# When will Neo4jClient support new features on Neo4j 2.0 new features. Labels etc

Tags: neo4j, neo4jclient

Neo4j 2.0 is going to be a major upgrade from version 1.8 and 1.9. What are the current plans to support some of the new features such a labels in Neo4jClient. We are in the midst of researching / selecting a NOSQL database for our enterprise and any inputs on the timeline will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When these issues are closed:

- https://bitbucket.org/Readify/neo4jclient/issue/78/support-new-cypher-clauses-available-in
- https://bitbucket.org/Readify/neo4jclient/issue/79/support-neo4j-20s-labels-in-basic-rest

From https://bitbucket.org/Readify/neo4jclient/wiki/Home:

> The library is predominantly written by consultants from [Readify](http://readify.net/). This is done in the course of supporting some of our commercial customers who use Neo4j, then as a general open source project on a best-effort basis. If you'd like something more guaranteed, or related Neo4j and .NET consulting services, [get in touch](http://mailto%3ainfo@readify.net).

Basically, the work is identified, but there are no schedules set for when it will be done. We'll get to it when we get to it. If you'd like it sooner, you can send a pull request to the project (the codebase is pretty simple) or you can contact Readify for commercial options.